# Python opencv поиск фрагмента на изображении

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Это код, который находит фото **two.png** на фото **one.jpg**.Он работает и сохраняет изображение, закрашивая один из фрагментов на фото жёлтым цветом. Повторяю это действие 4 раза и все 4 фрагмента отлично закрашиваются, но если продолжить запускать код, то он будет закрашивать пустые места на изображении. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы код находил только совпадающие фрагменты и закрашивал только их?

```
import cv2

method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

small_image = cv2.imread('two.png')
large_image = cv2.imread('one.jpg')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)

mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

MPx,MPy = mnLoc

trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]
h = (MPx + tcols//2)
v = (MPy + trows//2)

cv2.line(large_image, (MPx, (MPy+MPy+trows)//2), (MPx+tcols, (MPy+MPy+trows)//2), (0,255,255), thickness=20, lineType=8, shift=0)
cv2.imshow('one', large_image)
cv2.imwrite('one.jpg', large_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```